# Can I found an MSI Mothercard to instal my i7-2720QM (BGA1224)?

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i7

Good evening, everything is in this question "Can I found an MSI Mothercard to instal my  i7-2720QM (BGA1224) ?"

My laptop is HS (DELL XPS 17 L702X) I would like to know if I can find a motherboard preferably MSI to put this processor Intel i7.

And why use my memory cards (via an adapter)?

I have already reinstalled my BR player and DVD burner, my 2TB 2.5 "1TB (2 times 500 GB) and I recycled the 17" 3D screen via a friend who knows extremely well in wiring LCD screen.

Thanks for your understanding.

Regards,

---

Essential info

```
Previous Generation Intel® Core ™ Processor Product Set
Code Name Products formerly Sandy Bridge
Mobile Vertical Segment
Processor number i7-2720QM
Launched state
Launch date Q1'11
32 nm Lithography
```

performances

```
Nb. of hearts 4
Nb. of threads 8
Basic frequency 2.20 GHz
Max. Turbo frequency 3.30 GHz
Intel® Smart Cache 6 MB Cache
Bus speed 5 GT / s
PDT 45 W
```

Additional info

```
Embedded options available No
Data sheet Discover it now
```

Memory specifications

```
Maximum memory capacity (depends on the type of memory) 32 GB
DDR3 1066/1333/1600 memory types
Nb. max. memory channels 2
Maximum memory bandwidth 25.6 GB / s
ECC Memory Supported ‡ No
```

Graphic processor

```
Graphic processor Intel® HD 3000 Graphics Core
Basic graphic frequency 650 MHz
Maximum dynamic graphic frequency 1.30 GHz
EDP ​​/ DP / HDMI / SDVO / CRT graphics output
Intel® Quick Sync Video Technology Yes
Intel® InTru ™ 3D Technology Yes
Intel® FDI Interface (Flexible Display Interface) Yes
Intel® Clear Video HD Technology Yes
Macrovision License * required No
Nb. of screens supported ‡ 2
Device ID 0x116
```

Comment: There are no motherboard upgrades for laptops unless the manufacturer offers one, and Dell does not.

Comment: There are a few Chinese folks offering highly unofficial motherboard transplants for older ThinkPads (X60, X61, et al) with the really good keyboards.

Comment: Thank you, but I never wrote that I wanted to upgrade my laptop. I wrote that I wanted to know if I could use the processor i7 of my laptop on a motherboard normal ... Thank you to "K7AAY" who read my question and therefore answered well.

I'm going to put this processor in a 10 cm cube and pour resin into it to make a clipboard ...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no. [Ball Grid Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) CPU packages are for factory install only.

Comment: Thank you, I imagine that DELL should not be the only one to f..k us by putting i7 processors not usable elsewhere ... Pfff, and me who was happy to recycle this i7 ... :(

Which Motherboard MSI (or other brand, I'm not addict to MSI) would you advise me to make video processing in HD and incidentally (on the 2nd screen) a bit of internet?

Going on the new i9 is it plausible without too much ruin or stayed on an i7 is better?

Can you also advise me on a graphics card (the ideal being to have the same brand (motherboard and graphics card) I imagine, right?

Comment: You want to do video processing? Use a desktop, so you can keep upgrading it as performance expectations climb.